# About Custom Email Template Design Responsive

Tags: email, responsive, wp-register-style, html-email

I created a custom email function using wp_mail() function. I did everything which is required for mail template. This function is working well. But I need it to be responsive. I found that I can use only inline css in email template. This way there are few css could applied on email template. I can't use Position property of css and other so many css property doesn't work. How can I use external css so it look responsive. Please help.

Here is my code:

```php
// WP Mail function
function html_mail_content_type() {
    return 'text/html';
}
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'html_mail_content_type' );
// Function to change email address
function wpb_sender_email( $original_email_address ) {
    return $original_email_address;
}
 
// Function to change sender name
function wpb_sender_name( $original_email_from ) {
    return 'Admin';
}   
// Hooking up our functions to WordPress filters 
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', 'wpb_sender_email' );
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', 'wpb_sender_name' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_sent_email', 'sent_email' );
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_sent_email", "sent_email");

function sent_email() { 
    $to = 'test@test.com';
    $subject = "Thanks for submitting your information";
    $from = $_POST['user_email'];
    $customerName = $_POST['user_name'];
    $customerNumber = $_POST['phone'];
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers = array('From: Admin <admin@admin.com>',
                  'CC: <'.$_POST['user_email'].'>',);
$message = '<!DOCTYPE html>
                <html lang="en">
                <head>
                <title>Estimate Summary</title>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                </head>';
    $message .= '<body>';
    $message .= '<div>
                <div>
                <table style="border:2px solid #172c5b; width: 80%; margin: 0 auto;">
                        <tr >
                            <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid #172c5b; border-right: 1px solid #172c5b; text-align: left; font-size: 16px; padding-left: 15px;">Title</th>
                            <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid #172c5b; text-align: left; font-size: 16px;">Description</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: center;text-align: left; border-bottom: 1px solid #172c5b; border-right: 1px solid #172c5b; font-size: 16px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 40px;">Customer Name:</td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;text-align: left; border-bottom: 1px solid #172c5b;  font-size: 16px;">'.$customerName.'</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: center;text-align: left; border-bottom: 1px solid #172c5b; border-right: 1px solid #172c5b; font-size: 16px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 40px;">Customer Phone: </td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;text-align: left; border-bottom: 1px solid #172c5b; font-size: 16px;">'.$customerNumber.'</td>
                        </tr>
                            <td style="text-align: center;text-align: left; border-top: 1px solid #172c5b; border-bottom: 1px solid #172c5b; border-right: 1px solid #172c5b; font-size: 16px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 40px;">Moving To:</td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;text-align: left; border-bottom: 1px solid #172c5b; font-size: 16px;">City</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: center;text-align: left; border-bottom: 1px solid #172c5b; border-right: 1px solid #172c5b; font-size: 16px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 40px;">Types of Move:</td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;text-align: left; border-bottom: 1px solid #172c5b;  font-size: 16px;">Types</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: center;text-align: left; border-bottom: 1px solid #172c5b; border-right: 1px solid #172c5b; font-size: 16px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 25px;">Date </td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;text-align: left; border-bottom: 1px solid #172c5b; font-size: 16px;">21/12/2021</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                </div>';
    $message .= '</body></html>';
    $success = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, array( '' ) );
    if($success){
    echo 'Success'; 
    }
    else{
        echo 'Error';
    }
    exit();
}



It is just an example. Now Please help how can I add media queries for making it responsive.
```

Comment: The inline css its good enough, but why dont you give it classes or id's and then make the css style on the style file. that way its already possible to use any css inclueded queries and stuff...

Comment: thankyou for your reply. I added some classes and add style tag in head tag and my css worked but not media queries.

Comment: the email html is somewhat limited compared to the browser html, media queries will not work.  A wise man said, "html is responsive by nature", add just a few lines of css and make it wonderful